# Spring Cloud Sleuth and spring boot 3 and the english language

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

Sorry for asking that. I'm not an English speaker, and Stackoverflow is the only  website I have access to at my work

I need to use Spring Cloud Sleuth in a project currently in spring boot 2, but who will pass to spring boot 3 in a month?

I was reading the Spring Cloud Sleuth documentation and noticed that:

> Spring Cloud Sleuth will not work with Spring Boot 3.x onward. The
> last major version of Spring Boot that Sleuth will support is 2.x.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/index.html

Does this mean that the library is not currently compatible with Spring Boot 3 and there is no plan to make it work, or is work being done to make it compatible?

"My coworkers nor I am familiar with the meaning of "onward" in this context. The word does not translate well in my language."

Comment: I would parse that as does not work with 3.x or later, no changes expected. Only works with 2.x or lower.

Comment: By no change expected, you mean they don't plan to update the lib to allow springboot 3 ?

Comment: Correct, not even planned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Cloud Sleuth is not planned to work with Spring Boot 3. You must migrate to Micrometer Tracing. Here you can find a link to the migration guide https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.1-Migration-Guide